# Text Box to retrieve information from database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I'm trying to display information on a piece of equipment the idea is that the user will type in an ID in the textbox and it will display the information on a grid view:

```
 Dim ID As String = TxtSearch.Text
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand

        Dim ds As String = "Select * from Medical_Equipment where AssetID='" & ID & "''"
        Dim strConnString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        cmd = New SqlCommand(ds, con)


        Try
            con.Open()
            GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No equipment with that Asset ID"
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            GridView1.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

But it is not displaying the information Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '1001''.Incorrect syntax near '1001''

Comment: And your questions is....

Comment: As such, your code looks ok, what is your problem ?

Comment: Yes I've edited there I guess it has something to do with the integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AssetID` is defined as numeric at database level the SQL statement should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM Medical_Equipment WHERE AssetID=" & ID
```

If it is defined as text then should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM Medical_Equipment WHERE AssetID='" & ID & "'"
```

Comment: Also avoid doing your request like this for passing parameters. Read about SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo here:

Try this:

```
"Select * from Medical_Equipment where AssetID='" & ID & "'"
```